# Can't seem to import a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to import a subdocument into my Express/Mongoose API.

I have the following structure:

```
   models
       |-profile
       |    |-phones.js
       |
       |-profile.js
```

Here is the phones.js schema file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PhonesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  phone_number:{ type: String },
  phone_type:{ type: Number }
})



module.exports = mongoose.model('PhonesSchema', PhonesSchema);
```

Here is the profile.js parent document, which resides in the models folder:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  

var PhonesSchema = require('./profile/phones');

var ProfileSchema = new Schema({

  //PROFILE INFO
  owner_id: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true
  },
  linkedIn:{
    type: String
  },
  phones:[PhonesSchema],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show me your directory structure?

Comment: why are you defining a schema within a schema? just define your children as json objects...

Comment: @LostJon, my understanding is that this is a best practice, as it is a bit more of an OOP approach and will allow me to import and reused the schema blocks in other scenarios. I also think it provides a cleaner approach that will make it easier to manage code as these segments grow. What are your thoughts and is there a down-side to this approach?

Comment: Hi Ravi, I cleaned up the example a bit more. The parent schema is in the root of the models folder. The other files are in a subfolder (profiles). So the path of ./profile/phones should be right for the "require".

Comment: @cnak2 seems the issue is more with the fact that you export the model of the PhonesSchema as opposed to the schema. Instead of using `model.exports = mongoose.model('PhonesSchema',PhonesSchema)` you could just do `model.exports = PhonesSchema` and you should be set
 ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Thanks, LostJon! That worked.

Comment: @cnak2 glad that worked...can you mark as answer for cleanup purposes (i moved comment to answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the issue is more with the fact that you export the model of the PhonesSchema as opposed to the schema. Instead of using

```
model.exports = mongoose.model('PhonesSchema',PhonesSchema)
```

you should use:

```
model.exports = PhonesSchema
```

ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html